# Is raphael.js paper a real canvas?

Tags: raphael

I was researching what graphics to use for a project, and Raphael.js came to be a top contender.   However, when reading the sample code and documentation, it shows that Raphael creates a canvas (via the paper variable on the [homepage](http://raphaeljs.com/)), and then you add stuff to it.  Two months later, a passerby comes by and ask some question about our project, and I explained that we didn't use Raphael (instead we chose static SVG and D3) because Raphael used canvas's, and our project would have been greatly disadvantaged by using canvas's.  So you Raphael expert's out there, is the canvas in Raphael an actual html canvas or not? and where can you link to it, so that you/and or I can send a pull request to explain that better upfront.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No Raphael's paper is `SVG`.

It is kinda strange, because the paper object property is called `canvas` but it only contains the `SVGAnimatedString`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V2DGy/

Answer (score 3):

Raphael uses SVG and VML to create graphics. The variable `canvas` is simply named as canvas and is not a canvas element. In fact, it is the root SVG element associated with that specific paper.

Raphael is very much similar to d3 but is more on thd lines of a graphics library and the added advantage of compatibility with Internet Explorer 6 through 8 (using VML instead of SVG.)

Though the variable name is misleading, yet Raphael mentions upfront in their home page that it is SVG library.

Quoting their website.

---

Raphaël is a small JavaScript library that should simplify your work with vector graphics on the web. If you want to create your own specific chart or image crop and rotate widget, for example, you can achieve it simply and easily with this library.
Raphaël ['ræfeɪəl] uses the SVG W3C Recommendation and VML as a base for creating graphics. This means every graphical object you create is also a DOM object, so you can attach JavaScript event handlers or modify them later. Raphaël’s goal is to provide an adapter that will make drawing vector art compatible cross-browser and easy.
Raphaël currently supports Firefox 3.0+, Safari 3.0+, Chrome 5.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+.

Answer (score 1):

No. Is svg. Totally different. Canvas contains "a picture", svg contains vectorial elements.